# C++ - how to retrieve a pointer from a list of pointers (to store in a new object)

Tags: c++, pointers

I’m new to c++ and I have a question on how to retrieve a pointer from a list of pointers, and then store it in a new object. I’ve looked up several posts, but haven’t been able to find anything as general as this.

More specifically I have a group object. I have pointers to these group objects in a list. 
I then want to create event objects, and store pointers to those event objects in an event list. Each event object should point to the specific group that it’s related to in order to later reference that data. And the event objects have to be created after the group objects.

I’m not sure how to retrieve the correct group pointer from the group list to add to the new event though. 
I don’t think this would work with iterators because I don’t think each one would be persistent throughout the entire code cycle and i got a bunch of wrong parameter type compilation errors . Would be appreciative of any general or specific direction!

My Condensed code below.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>  
#include <list> 

using namespace std;

class Group{
    Public:
        int m_groupCode;

    Group(int code){
        m_groupCode = code;
        /// plus some other stuff
    }   
};

class Event{
    public:
      string m_somestuffA;
      Group * m_groupPtr;

      Event(string a, Group * ptr){
         m_somestuffA = a;
         m_groupPt = ptr;
      }

      ~Event(){  
          delete m_groupPtr;
       }
};

Int main (){
    List < Group*> groupList;
    for (int i = 0; i<10, i++){
        groupList.push_back(new Group( i ) );
    }

// I’m not sure how to get the pointer to the specific group to add to 
//the new event
// how can I replace the below ??? with a pointer to a specific group 
//either based on the group code or possibly even the group position in 
//the group list

    List < Event* > eventList;
        for (int i = 0; i<10, i++){
            eventList.push_back(new Group(“somestuff”, ???  ) );
        } 
}
```

Comment: What's a `List`? Why are you including those `.h` headers?

Comment: Group and Event aren't related by inheritance. You won't be able to store Group pointers in a list expecting Event pointers.  Why not have each group object contain a list of events? It's not really clear what your goal is. Perhaps explain why you're trying to do this rather than your specific implementation, because there's likely a better design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
Int main (){
    vector < Group*> groupList;
    vector < Event* > eventList;

    for (int i = 0; i<10, i++){
        Group *group= new Group(i);
        groupList.push_back(group);

        eventList.push_back(new Event( "something",group));
    }
}
```